# After "sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin" in Ubuntu 18.04.1 and restart, I no longer see the desktop, only black screen after login

Tags: keyboard, login, input-language, pinyin

My story is like this:

1. opened "*setting*", changed keyboard input from "*ibus*" into "*fcitx*"
2. in a terminal, installed google pinyin for ubuntu by:
   *$sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin*
3. restarted the laptop.
4. At the login page, I input password to login. Then, forever black screen, desktop failed to load.

Then, I tried to solve the problem by uninstalling fcitx-googlepinyin by the following:

s1. keyboard *ctrl+alt+F3*, enter TTY, the terminal version of the system.

s2. tried the following three ways of **removing fcitx-googlepinyin**, together with a **restart**, and failed.

```
*$sudo apt-get remove  fcitx-googlepinyin* 

*$sudo apt-get remove --autoremove fcitx-googlepinyin*

*$sudo apt-get autoremove --purge fcitx-googlepinyin*
```

May I ask, do you know how could I enter the normal desktop of the ubuntu? How could one save all the user files to portable storage from the terminal? After that, one can safely re-install the system. Thank you.

Comment: Log in into a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F3), run the command `im-config -n ibus` and reboot.

Comment: Thank you, Gunnar.
The command solved my problem fluently. : -)

Comment: Good. I have no idea why you run into that kind of issue by switching to `fcitx` though. It shouldn't have stopped you from entering a graphical session.

Comment: I am also wondering where is the potential incompatibility between, fcitx and *#55~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP, X86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: If you need help to install it properly you may want to ask a new question (and close this one).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by [Mr. Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) in the comment under my questions. Lots of thanks.

*Log in into a **TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F3)**, run the command **im-config -n ibus** and **reboot**. – Gunnar Hjalmarsson*

However, how this could have happened, is still unclear.